# How do I install kernel documentation for a custom kernel?

Tags: kernel, compiling, documentation

I build my own kernel occasionally and install the resultant deb files (from bindeb-pkg). I know I can run the command `make htmldocs` in the kernel build folder but how do I get those into the deb files so that they are installed as well? Or to somehow install the rst versions? I assume a web browser can interpret those.

Ubuntu 23.04.

Thanks.